# can't update database symfony 4 with sonataClassificationBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata, symfony-sonata

im using Symfony 4.1

When you install SonataMediaBundle and SonataClassificationBundle after configure the both of them.
and you want execute the commande

php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

you got this Error

`The table with name 'shop.classification__collection' already exists.`

same for all other table of classification like category and tag 
if you try to change the name of table in the entity of classification__collection to classification_collection

you will get a second error like

`An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tag_collection ON classification__collection (slug, context):

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length  is 767 bytes`

Answer (score 2):

I run in this problem recently and find the solution.

The issue is address here

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataClassificationBundle/issues/407

You just need to remove the entity created in App/Entity by classification or remapped the class to the App/Entity in sonata.yaml and sonata_classification.yaml

If you deleted the entities in App/Entity add the following cofiguration to your sonata.yaml and sonata_classification.yaml

/**  sonata_classification.yaml**/

```
sonata_classification:
    class:
       tag: App\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Tag
       category: App\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category
       media: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
       collection: App\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Collection
       context: App\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Context
```

/**  sonata.yaml**/

```
class:
    media: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
    gallery: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
    gallery_has_media: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
    category: App\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category
```